# how to use objectId in a query .net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, objectid

I need to insert (or create) a field in different documents (`MongoDB`).
 That's my code:

```
var myDB = mclient.GetDatabase("MasterDB"); 
var collection = myDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MasterCollection");
var list = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument())
                           .Limit(2) 
                           .Skip(1)
                           .ToListAsync();

foreach (var docs in list)
{               
    var updoneresult1 = await collection.UpdateManyAsync(
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", docs["_id"].ToString()),
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Push("OfficeCode", 
    Convert.ToInt32(txtOfficeCode.Text)));     
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you have an error?

Comment: I haven't an error but it doesn't work, i was wondering if i can match the ObjectId of the docoument with the ObjectId of docs. I'm trying to add the "OfficeCode" field in 2 different document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thiink you need add:
http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_Add_2.htm

```
foreach (var docs in list)
{ 
    ....          
    docs.Add("OfficeCode", Convert.ToInt32(txtOfficeCode.Text));
    ....
}
```

PS I don't really know what you are trying to acomplish here.

EDIT:

in comments you said you have trouble matching it by _id. Try changing

`docs["_id"].ToString()`

to

```
ObjectId.Parse(docs["_id"].ToString())
```

Comment: it still doesn't working, i've tryed with matching another field instead the ObjectId and it works.. but now i need to match the "_id" field